# Mapping association between different bundles - Doctrine/Symfony2

Tags: entity-framework, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I read many questions related to this error on stackoverflow. However, none of them seems to answer my question. I wonder if someone could help me.

I have two bundles (CoreBundle and EcommerceBundle) and a bidirectional relationship between their entities (User and CustomerGroup). The getters and setters were created using the doctrine:generate:entities so I know that it recognized the path to the other bundle. However, once I open a page where I have a form to edit the user profile, the debug bar tells me:

> The association MyCompany\EcommerceBundle\Entity\CustomerGroup#users refers to the owning side field MyCompany\CoreBundle\Entity\User#customerGroup which does not exist.

After have reviewed the association many times, I cannot figured out why Doctrine does not recognize the owning side field. It is well defined as you can see in the code below:

**User entity from the Core Bundle**

```
namespace MyCompany\CoreBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="mycompany_user")
 * @ORMEntity(repositoryClass="MyCompany\CoreBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MyCompany\EcommerceBundle\Entity\CustomerGroup", inversedBy="users")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="customer_group", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $customerGroup;

    /**
     * Set customerGroup
     *
     * @param \MyCompany\EcommerceBundle\Entity\CustomerGroup $customerGroup
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setCustomerGroup(\MyCompany\EcommerceBundle\Entity\CustomerGroup $customerGroup = null)
    {
        $this->customerGroup = $customerGroup;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get customerGroup
     *
     * @return \MyCompany\EcommerceBundle\Entity\CustomerGroup
     */
    public function getCustomerGroup()
    {
        return $this->customerGroup;
    }
}
```

**CustomerGroup entity from the Ecommerce Bundle**

```
namespace MyCompany\EcommerceBundle\Entity;

/**
 * CustomerGroup
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="mycompany_ecommerce_customer_group")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MyCompany\EcommerceBundle\Entity\CustomerGroupRepository")
 */
class CustomerGroup
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="MyCompany\CoreBundle\Entity\User", mappedBy="customerGroup")
     */
    protected $users;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->users = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Add user
     *
     * @param \MyCompany\CoreBundle\Entity\User $user
     *
     * @return CustomerGroup
     */
    public function addUser(\MyCompany\CoreBundle\Entity\User $user)
    {
        $this->users[] = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove user
     *
     * @param \MyCompany\CoreBundle\Entity\User $user
     */
    public function removeUser(\MyCompany\CoreBundle\Entity\User $user)
    {
        $this->users->removeElement($user);
    }

    /**
     * Get users
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getUsers()
    {
        return $this->users;
    }
}
```

And both bundles are defined on my config.yml:

```
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    entity_managers:
        default:
            connection:       default
            filters:
                notDeletable:
                    class: MyCompany\CoreBundle\Doctrine\Filter\SoftDeletableFilter
                    enabled: true
            mappings:
                MyCompanyCoreBundle: ~
                MyCompanyEcommerceBundle: ~
```

Comment: I guess your cache is clear...

Comment: What do you mean @pabgaran ? I cleared the cache many times during my tests and it didn't help.

Comment: Sorry... I mean clean

Comment: @user3489615 Where is your id field on your CustomerGroup entity? Should it also not extend some base class?

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be in the way your `User` class extends `BaseUser`. Is your  `BaseUser` class [a proper doctrine `MappedSuperClass`](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#mapped-superclasses)?

If not this might lead to doctrine having issues validating and creating your entities correctly.

Please post your `BaseUser` class definition and you could try once without extending `BaseUser` and see if you have the same issues...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments. I found the problem when @pabgaran posted about the cache. I was clearing the symfony cache. I read the doc again and I saw that the doctrine cache is related to the APC cache so I cleared it too. After that, it worked fine.

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/caching.html